# Doubt regarding reputation change

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I got a change in my reputation that said:

> -5 User was removed

What does this mean? When I open this notification, it redirects to my home page!

Comment: Actually there is no point which says if a user is removed, there will be any reputation changes. I'm guessing maybe the user who was removed upvoted on one of my questions.

Comment: Quote from the dupe link: "*... This event is also used when a [user is removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/246262).*"

Comment: I got that @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, thanks :)